# php curl getting back empty content

Tags: php, curl, https

Hey there I have been looking around for a solution for the problem for a while now, but no luck so far...basically, I want to pull down a page content using curl in PHP. And the following is the code

```php
  static function getContent($url) {
    // pull down the content that the url pointing to 
    $curl = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, false);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true); 
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, Constants::$USER_AGENT_CHROME);
    $cookie = realpath(Constants::$ROOT_DIR . Constants::$COOKIE);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookie);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_2_0);
    // curl_setopt ($curl, CURLOPT_CAINFO, dirname(__FILE__).'/cacert.pem');
    $content = curl_exec($curl);
    curl_close($curl);
    return $content;
  }
```

And the call to the function with the following url always returns me empty content and had no problem so far with other different urls (from different domains) that I tried.

$url = 'https://www.etsy.com/listing/150723421/iretrofone-20-steampunk-silver';

Any reason why?

[EDIT] I ran this script on Amazon Linux, something might be missing on the machine such that the issue got exposed. The two answers so far didn't work with me.

[EDIT] The following is the curl_getinfo output

```
{"url":"https:\/\/www.etsy.com\/listing\/150723421\/iretrofone-20-steampunk-silver","content_type":"text\/html; charset=UTF-8","http_code":200,"header_size":737,"request_size":287,"filetime":-1,"ssl_verify_result":0,"redirect_count":0,"total_time":0.404801,"namelookup_time":0.028505,"connect_time":0.065447,"pretransfer_time":0.243564,"size_upload":0,"size_download":0,"speed_download":0,"speed_upload":0,"download_content_length":0,"upload_content_length":-1,"starttransfer_time":0.40422,"redirect_time":0,"redirect_url":"","primary_ip":"199.27.79.249","certinfo":[],"primary_port":443,"local_ip":"172.31.29.192","local_port":44605}
```

[EDIT] the following is the verbose output

```
*   Trying 23.41.253.83...
* Connected to www.etsy.com (23.41.253.83) port 443 (#0)
* Initializing NSS with certpath: sql:/etc/pki/nssdb
* skipping SSL peer certificate verification
* SSL connection using TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
* Server certificate:
*       subject: CN=*.etsy.com,OU=Ops,O=Etsy Inc,L=Secaucus,ST=AL,C=US
*       start date: Feb 17 18:11:39 2015 GMT
*       expire date: Feb 17 18:11:37 2016 GMT
*       common name: *.etsy.com
*       issuer: CN=Verizon Akamai SureServer CA G14-SHA2,OU=Cybertrust,O=Verizon Enterprise Solutions,L=Amsterdam,C=NL
> GET /listing/150723421/iretrofone-20-steampunk-silver HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/46.0.2490.80 Safari/537.36
Host: www.etsy.com
Accept: */*
Cookie: uaid=uaid%3DYtum0fFFHW4vd8Fy0IIrtOqKsfXg%26_now%3D1446093672%26_slt%3DDsQSnzXs%26_kid%3D1%26_ver%3D1%26_mac%3DsGZ19jZbFEmxLRCZ87q_mSuvLbRtRjH4LjAYFO74NGg.

< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Server: Apache
< Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
< Cache-Control: private, no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
< Content-Length: 0
< X-Cnection: close
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
< Date: Fri, 30 Oct 2015 16:20:53 GMT
< Connection: keep-alive
* Replaced cookie uaid="uaid%3DYtum0fFFHW4vd8Fy0IIrtOqKsfXg%26_now%3D1446222053%26_slt%3D2FNk-6Hh%26_kid%3D1%26_ver%3D1%26_mac%3DsgAm5o2-yY7aTA7Zt0H4gbSfoCf57mdL9KRraF65fig." for domain etsy.com, path /, expire 1480408753
< Set-Cookie: uaid=uaid%3DYtum0fFFHW4vd8Fy0IIrtOqKsfXg%26_now%3D1446222053%26_slt%3D2FNk-6Hh%26_kid%3D1%26_ver%3D1%26_mac%3DsgAm5o2-yY7aTA7Zt0H4gbSfoCf57mdL9KRraF65fig.; expires=Tue, 29-Nov-2016 08:39:13 GMT; Max-Age=34186700; path=/; domain=.etsy.com; httponly
<
* Connection #0 to host www.etsy.com left intact
```

Comment: i tested your code and i got the contents on my localhost php 5.5 maybe there's something with your installation just try the code in another machine

Answer (score 0):

Try this code, its working with no cookie.

```
<?php
 function getContent($url) {
 $curl = curl_init($url);
 curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
 curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
 $data = curl_exec($curl);
 curl_close($curl);
 return $data;
}

 $url = 'https://www.etsy.com/listing/150723421/iretrofone-20-steampunk-silver';

 echo $a = getContent($url);
?>
```

Comment: Did you install curl in your server?